# convert day-number within the year to month/day format

Tags: r, date, posix, julian-date

I am trying to convert a day-number within the year to month/day format.

With this df:

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(Year = rep(15,100), DayNum = seq(78,177,1), Hour = sample(0:23,100,replace = T))
df2 <- data.frame(Year = rep(16,100), DayNum = seq(78,177,1), Hour = sample(0:23,100,replace = T))

df <- rbind(df1, df2)
> head(df)
  Year DayNum Hour
1   15     78    6
2   15     79   18
3   15     80    9
4   15     81   21
5   15     82   22
6   15     83    1
> tail(df)
    Year DayNum Hour
195   16    172   22
196   16    173   11
197   16    174    9
198   16    175   15
199   16    176    3
200   16    177   13
```

which has 100 records for 2015 and 2016, how can I make a `POSIXct` date/time column?

While there are a number of related posts with a Julian date from a beginning origin (usually 1970-01-01), I could not find any posts with a day-number within a year and with a variable year (i.e. 2015 and 2016).

Comment: That's not a 'Julian' date, it is just the day-number within the year. _Julian Date_ has a clear definition - _"Julian day is the continuous count of days since the beginning of the Julian Period used primarily by astronomers."_ - with 0 = January 1, 4713 BC.

Comment: You can change your origin to be whatever you want, for example `2015-01-01`

Comment: @Aganju I have edited the question to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need something like this, use `%j` to specify the day of the year:

```
strptime(with(df, paste(Year, DayNum, Hour)), "%y %j %H")

# [1] "2015-03-19 06:00:00 EDT"
# [2] "2015-03-20 18:00:00 EDT"
# [3] "2015-03-21 09:00:00 EDT"
# [4] "2015-03-22 21:00:00 EDT"
# [5] "2015-03-23 22:00:00 EDT"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `as.POSIXct` function has an option to specify the origin date when converting from a "Julian" date to the date/time object:

```
#calculate the origin date based on the year column
df$origin<-as.Date(paste0("20", df$Year,"-01-01"))
#convert the Julian day to a date/time object
as.POSIXct(df$JulianDay, origin=df$origin)
```

One may need to consider adding the timezone option for completeness:

```
 as.POSIXct(df$JulianDay, origin=df$origin, tz="GMT")
```